# time data '2020–04–29 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am getting this error

```
time data '2020–04–29 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

input for start date is '2020–04–29'

I am trying to srap tweets using twint and I am geting this error

`

```
config = twint.Config()
    config.Pandas = True

    payload = json.dumps(request.GET)
    payload = json.loads(payload)
    

    config.Search = payload.get('keyword')
    config.Lang = payload.get('language','en')
    config.Limit = int(payload.get('limit',100))
    startDate = payload.get("startDate",None)
    if startDate:
        config.Since = startDate

    endDate = payload.get("endDate",None)
    print(startDate,endDate)
    if endDate:
        config.Until = endDate    
    
    

    twint.run.Search(config)
```

`

Answer (score 3):

The `–` is *not* a hyphen (`-`), but an [*en dash* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) with codepoint `0x2013`. You thus parse this with:

```
startDate = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y–%m–%d %H:%M:%S')
```